# Custom installer for out of browser (oob) application. The update does not work

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-5.0, silverlight-oob

I want to create a custom installer for oob applications for Windows and MacOS.

For Windows, I used the following method - https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/179756/Installing-Silverlight-OOB-Application-using-a-Set

For MacOS, the following solution - https://www.blaize.net/2012/04/offline-oob-mac-installation/

These methods work well and create the application, but the application update does not work with them.

In the Silverlight application, I use the following code to update:

```
private void CheckUpdateApplication()
{
    if (Application.Current.IsRunningOutOfBrowser)
    {
        Application.Current.CheckAndDownloadUpdateAsync();
        Application.Current.CheckAndDownloadUpdateCompleted += Application_CheckAndDownloadUpdateCompleted;
    }
}

private void Application_CheckAndDownloadUpdateCompleted(object sender, CheckAndDownloadUpdateCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.UpdateAvailable)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(CommonMethod.MessageUpdateApplication);
    }
    else if (e.Error != null)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(string.Format("{0} - {1}", e.Error.GetType().Name, e.Error.Message));
    }
}
```

In the settings of out of browser application, I set the checkbox - "Require elevated trust when running outside the browser". The XAP file is signed with a self-signed certificate.

After installing in Windows, I get the following error when updating:

> Exception - Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a
>   COM component.

After installing in MacOS, I get the following:

> OutOfMemoryException - Error 0x1AA6.

Answer (score 0):

Pass the `/origin` command line argument to `sllauncher.exe`

From https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/179756/Installing-Silverlight-OOB-Application-using-a-Set:

> This option specifies the Uri where the XAP file have come from. This
>   Uri is used for security purposes and auto-updates. For example:
>   /origin: http://mywebsite.com/SampleOOB.xap